# Delegated Admin not being able to create users for assigned profile

Tags: administration, system-admin, delegated-admin

I have created a delegated group and have assigned a user to it. Under assignable profiles,I have assigned a Chatter Free profile. But the user is still not being able to create users for that profile. Can anyone tell me why? It is showing insufficient privilege

Comment: what is the profile of delegated administrator?

Comment: have tried and it working fine.